# Optimization with intervals

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve a specific problem, and I was able to summarize it in the following optimization problem.

I have a portfolio comprised of two assets. Asset 1 has return $r_1$, standard deviation $\sigma_1$ and weight $w_1$ in portfolio, and Asset 2 has return $r_2$, standard deviation $\sigma_2$ and weight $w_2$ in portfolio.

We are trying to determine the value of $x$ that will maximize the following ratio:

$max$  $\frac{w_1 r_1 + w_2r_2}{\sqrt{w_1  \sigma_1^2 + w_2  \sigma_2^2 +  w_1  w_2  \sigma_1  \sigma_2 \rho}}$

s.t.

$ w_1 = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $p_t \leq x$}\\
    \frac{p_t - 0.32}{0.32 - x} & \quad \text{if $x < p_t \leq 0.32$}\\
   0 & \quad \text{if $p_t$ > 0.32}
  \end{array} \right.$

$w_2 = 1 - w_1$

where $p_t$ is the value of $p$ at time $t$.

The inputs we have are: the time-series of $r_1$ and $r_2$ (hence we know $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$), and we have a time-series of the parameter $p$.

How can I solve this problem to find the value of $x$? 
Any help would be appreciated, as I am a little lost! Thank you!

Comment: You maximizing the Sharpe ratio I guess. But I don't get the meaning of the expression for $p$ and $x$. If $p$ is a time series, what does $p\leq x$ means?

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to maximize the sharpe ratio. So $p$ is a known parameter that changes over time. At each point in time, the value of $p$ with respect to the unknown value $x$ determines the weight structure. Imagine if $p_t$ is the value of market stress at time $t$. We need to determine the lower bound $x$. If we find that $x = 0.2$ for example, this means that if at time $t$ the market stress index $p$ is less than 0.2, then $w_1 = 1$, and $w_2 = 0$.

Comment: I have added a subscript $t$ for the parameter $p$ in the constraint. Thanks!

Comment: I see...so you solve a problem for a given value of $p$. But then either $w_1$ is constant, or you get $w_1(0.32-x)=p-0.32$ which is not convex.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I am following... Could you please explain? Something I forgot to mention: $x$ is a constant, it is not changing over time.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood..are $x,p$ positive? In any case, for $p>0.32$ you have $w_1=0$. But for $x<p<0.32$ $w_1$ is negative unless you allow $x$ to be negative.

Comment: Yes, $x$ and $p$ can be negative. Sorry again for not mentioning that.

Comment: @AC_MOSEK Thank you so much for trying to help. Were you by any chance, able to get to some sort of solution?

Comment: Ok..so actually $w_1$ can be either $0$ for $p\geq 0.32$ or a piece-wise function of $x$. In the latter case $w_1$ is either $1$ for $x>p$ or a concave function of $x$. So basically you can distinguish 3 cases, 2 being easy, the third quite difficult!

Comment: Would there be any program that would be able to approximate the solution?

Comment: When $w_1$ is constant, it can be solved by any QP or SOCP solver, as MOSEK for which I work. The other case is difficult and needs to be studied more deeply. Since we are talking about about 3 variables, if x has a lower bound you can solve a sequence of problems for fixed set  of $x$ values. Otherwise there are methods based on homotopies for global optimization as in "Cassioli, A., et al. "Optimization and homotopy methods for the Gibbs free energy of magmatic mixtures.". But you should check if you cannot find a convex formulation or approximation instead.

Comment: Actually for fixed $w_1$ the solution is trivial with 2 assets...

Comment: Unfortunately, since $p$ varies over time, then $w_1$ and $w_2$ also vary over time.. I guess there is no easy way to solve this problem...

Comment: Thank you for trying anyways!

Comment: You are welcome! Its sounds an interesting variant of the Sharpe ratio I didn't know about. I would suggest you to use the conic formulation to start with. If you can writing down with some more details, I'd take a look a little bit in detail. Or contact me in chat if you want.